# How to put label on my select?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have code like this which I executed from backend :

```
      $statement = $PDO->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($parameters);

        if($statement->rowCount()>0)
        {
            $resultSet = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($resultSet as $key => $value) 
            {

                $return .= "<option value='".$resultSet[$key]['bwid']."'>".$resultSet[$key]['bname']." - ".$resultSet[$key]['final_count']."</option>";


            }
        }
        else
        {
            $return = "<option>$lbldisp_text_nosuppfound</option>";
        }
        echo json_encode($return);
```

How do I put a label that says "**choose branch**" (i want it as the first option) ?

Thank you.

Comment: by adding a `<label>` tag before your select for example ?

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't work for me. Seems like i have to do it from the code that i posted. But i have no idea how to put it there

Comment: can you provide the generated html and all the php code related to `$return` 
please ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply append your label to the $return variable

```
$return .= '<label>Write text here</label>';
$return .= "<option value='".$resultSet[$key]['bwid']."'>".$resultSet[$key]['bname']." - ".$resultSet[$key]['final_count']."</option>";
echo $return;
```

Comment: yes, it shows this from my response in firebug
<label>Write text here</label><option value='12'>J2 - 33</option><label>Write text here</label><option
 value='12'>J2 - 33</option><label>Write text here</label><option value='13'>J3 - 25</option><label>Write
 text here</label><option value='12'>J2 - 33</option><label>Write text here</label><option value='13'
>J3 - 25</option>

Comment: Are you using ajax? If so, you need to add the response to the html of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a label tag and write your label text inside it.

```
$return .= "<label>choose branch</label>";
$return .= "<option value='".$resultSet[$key]['bwid']."'>".$resultSet[$key]['bname']." - ".$resultSet[$key]['final_count']."</option>";
```

Comment: nothing happening, But in my console response, it shows this.
"<label>**choose branch**<\/label><option value='12'>J2 - 33<\/option><label>**choose branch**<\/label
><option value='13'>J3 - 25<\/option><label>**choose branch**<\/label><option value='11'>J1 - 21<\/option
>"

Comment: Why don't you put this label above select tag? Or do you want it for each option?

Comment: Nope, I want it  as the first option.

Comment: My pleasure. Kindly upvote if it helped you any way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Hello @chrisjai32 try this out

    <div id="part">
    <label>choose branch</label>
    <input type="text" id="" placeholder="Branch Name" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="branch_id" id="branch_id">
    <div id="branch_options">
        <option value="0">--choose branch--</option>
        <?php foreach("$branches as $b") { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $b->branch_id; ?>">
            <?php echo $c->branch_name; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are the two inputs before the options ? and where is the `<select>` element ?

Comment: The first input defind type of text to be enter into the label ie numeric/text. the ID of that input and its placeholder. In the second input you should specify if you want data to be hidden or not. the name references the the brench_id and id=branch_id

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add a  element surrounding the options to have a valid html document.

Then you can add a disabled option in your select

```
if($statement->rowCount()>0){
    $resultSet = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $result = '<label>Choose your branch</label><select>'; //open the select and add the label
    $result .= '<option selected disabled>Choose branch</option>'; // add a disabled option with label
    foreach ($resultSet as $key => $value) {
        $return .= "<option value='".$resultSet[$key]['bwid']."'>".$resultSet[$key]['bname']." - ".$resultSet[$key]['final_count']."</option>";
    }

    $result .= '</select>'; // close the select
} else {
    $return = "<option>$lbldisp_text_nosuppfound</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to add a label "choose branch" to your select as the first option so it appears in the list not as a `<label>`. To achieve this you need to add a new option in the list but disable it and set it as selected.

Before you start adding the options to `$return` with the foreach loop add this line:

```
$return .= "<option selected disabled>choose branch</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

@chrisjai32 this is the script of my above answer

```
 <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                       $(document).on("click", "#check_branches", function(e){
                           branch_id = $("#branch_id").val();

                           $.ajax({
                              type: "GET",
                              url: "<?php echo url('/'); ?>/check_branch/"+brand_id,
                              success:function(result){
                                  $("#result").html("available " + result);
                              }

                           });
                           return false;
                       });
                    });
                    </script>
```